# Increment div id in loop

Tags: php

I want to incrementally add div id's to the images that are output but cannot figure out quite how to get it working. For example the first image output would have ".featured_1", the next will have ".featured_2" etc.

**The code i'm using**

```
if( function_exists('dfi_get_featured_images') ){
   $featuredImages = dfi_get_featured_images();

   //Now loop through the image to display your image

   if( !is_null($featuredImages) ){

        $links = array();

        foreach($featuredImages as $images){
            $thumb = $images['thumb'];
            $fullImage = $images['full'];

            $links[] = "<li class='zoom'><img class='zoomImg' src='{$thumb}' alt='' height='{$height}' width='{$width}' /></li>";
        }

        foreach($links as $link){
          echo $link;
        }
        echo "<div style='clear:both'></div>";
        echo "</ul>";
     }

}
```

**My failed attempt**

```
    $i=1
    foreach($featuredImages as $images){
        $thumb = $images['thumb'];
        $fullImage = $images['full'];

        $links[] = "<li class='zoom featured_".$i."'><img class='zoomImg' src='{$thumb}' alt='' height='{$height}' width='{$width}' /></li>";
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: That's the class, not the ID

Comment: But what is the problem? It seems to be right!

Comment: Apart from a syntax error and that you're setting a class not an id it looks right but you don't need to set $i like that. `foreach($featuredImages as $i=>$images){`

Comment: The code i'm using gives a unexpected T_FOREACH error

Comment: Why didn't you say that before? The problem is the syntax error

Comment: Well i said it was a failed attempt, but didn't realise the importance of noting why my code was wrong. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The code i'm using gives a unexpected T_FOREACH error"

```
$i=1
foreach($featuredImages as $images){
```

You have a syntax error (missing semicolon)

```
$i=1;
foreach($featuredImages as $images){
```

That out of the way, there's a lot of code for what you really need

```
    foreach($featuredImages as $i=>$images){
        echo "<li class='zoom'><img class='zoomImg' src='".$images['thumb']."' alt='' height='{$height}' width='{$width}' /></li>";
    }
```

Comment: Ah, what an idiot i am. Thanks. That gets rid of the error, just need to figure out now how to make the code attach to the images.

Comment: Actually, it's working fine now. Thanks a lot and sorry for not mentioning the error in my initial post.